# Why is the xml not modified?

Tags: xquery

I have a series of Query that in BaseX work and show me that they really mock the xml, but when I go to my xml it has not been modified.
this is my query

```
insert nodes <evaluacion>10</evaluacion> as last into doc(/"../BD/colecciones.xml")//libro[@publicacion=2007]
```

I have tried 2 ways as above and this way

```
insert nodes <evaluacion>10</evaluacion> as last into //libro[@publicacion=2007]
```

both ways work X-based on the results if it shows it but then I go to the xml and it hasn't changed for me.
I put the XML in case you want to test

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Fichero: libros.xml -->
<biblioteca>
 <libros>
  <libro publicacion="2003" edicion="2">
    <titulo>Learning XML</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Ray</apellido>
      <nombre>Erik T.</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>O'Reilly</editorial>
    <paginas>416</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2003" edicion="2">
    <titulo>XML Imprescindible</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Harold</apellido>
      <nombre>Elliot Rusty</nombre>
    </autor>
    <autor>
    <apellido>Means</apellido>
      <nombre>W. Scott</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>O'Reilly</editorial>
    <paginas>832</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2002">
    <titulo>XML Schema</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>van der Vlist</apellido>
      <nombre>Eric</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>O'Reilly</editorial>
    <paginas>400</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2002">
    <titulo>XPath Essentials</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Watt</apellido>
      <nombre>Adrew</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>Wiley</editorial>
    <paginas>516</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2005">
    <titulo> Beginning XSLT 2.0: Form Novice to Professional</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Tennison</apellido>
      <nombre>Jeni</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>Apress</editorial>
    <paginas>797</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2007">
    <titulo> XQuery</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Walmsley</apellido>
      <nombre>Priscilla</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>O'Reilly</editorial>
    <paginas>491</paginas>
  </libro>
 </libros>

<!-- Tabla prestamos -->
 <prestamos>
  <entrada>
    <titulo>XML Imprescindible</titulo>
    <prestamo>
      <inicio>2011-05-02</inicio>
      <lector>
        <nombre>Pepito</nombre>
        <apellidos>Grillo</apellidos>
        <direccion>Rue Percebe, 13</direccion>
        <telefono>972987654</telefono>
      </lector>
    </prestamo>
  </entrada>
  <entrada>
    <titulo>XML Imprescindible</titulo>
    <prestamo>
      <inicio>2011-02-12</inicio>
      <devolucion>2011-02-16</devolucion>
      <lector>
        <nombre>Jose</nombre>
        <apellidos>GutiÃ©rrez GonzÃ¡lez</apellidos>
        <direccion>Rue Percebe, 13</direccion>
        <telefono>919485432</telefono>
      </lector>
    </prestamo>
  </entrada>
  <entrada>
    <titulo>XPath Essentials</titulo>
    <prestamo>
      <inicio>2011-02-23</inicio>
      <devolucion>2011-03-10</devolucion>
      <lector>
        <nombre>Pepito</nombre>
        <apellidos>Grillo</apellidos>
        <direccion>Rue Percebe, 13</direccion>
        <telefono>972987654</telefono>
      </lector>
    </prestamo>
  </entrada>
 </prestamos>
</biblioteca>
```

the query says the following: Insert the evaluation node and whose content is 10 as the last node in the publication = 2007

Comment: So how do you run the XQuery code, with BaseX? Is the document you want to change part of a database?

Comment: See also http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#Original_Files.

Comment: When to use BaseX create a database, but not if I know when I use an update query I should modify the xml or just the DB

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did:

```
for $i in //libros/libro where $i/@publicacion = 2007 return insert node <evaluacion>10</evaluacion> as last into $i
```